# Mongodb aggregate returns a Circular Json Object, while in shell it returns a json?

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, shell, express

Im making a nodejs application which would return an array(assuming its a random array) of documents. I'm using aggregate function from mongodb and `$sample` operator.

if i run a query like `db.factslist.aggregate({ $sample: { size: 10 } }).pretty()` in mongo shell, it returns 10 documents. But if im running the same query in nodejs it complains about `circular json`

```
// GET an array of 10 Random Facts
  app.get('/facts', (req, res) => {
      var factitems= [];
      var objt= {};
        db.collection('factslist').aggregate({ $sample: { size: 10 } },(err, item) => {
          if (err) {
            res.send({'error':'An error has occurred while fetching data'});
          } else {
            factitems.push(item);
            objt.randomArray = factitems;
            res.send(objt);
          }
        });
  });
```

the error is as below

```
/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:132
      throw err;
      ^

TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at stringify (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1119:12)
    at ServerResponse.json (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:260:14)
    at ServerResponse.send (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:158:21)
    at db.collection.aggregate (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/app/routes/fact_routes.js:103:17)
    at handleCallback (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:128:55)
    at Collection.aggregate (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:2504:10)
    at app.get (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/app/routes/fact_routes.js:96:36)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/jon/wspace/RandomFacts/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
```

Comment: I've started getting this error after updating Mongo. The document it returns is much bigger too, i'm guessing something has changed

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem. After upgrading MongoDb driver from 2.2 to 3.0.4. I was trying to debug my query but it turned out that the problem lies in different usage of aggregate function.

Try this:

```
db.collection('collection_name').aggregate(query).toArray(function(err, data){
...
});
```